# is the only way we see skylight through scattering?

Tags: optics, visible-light

if when the sun is overhead and blue light is scattered, and red light is less scattered and therefore passes through the atmosphere, why do we not see rays of red light coming through?

Comment: To answer your title question, consider the photos taken from the Moon's surface during the Moon daytime and the sky's appearance in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the un-scattered red light is coming to you directly from the sun and if you look directly at the sun all you see is the bright sun !

If you look at the sun in the evening when it is low to the ground and more blue light has been scattered you do see it looking red = a sunset.